# Sql Server run update stored procedure after insert stored procedure

Tags: c#, .net, t-sql, stored-procedures, insert

I have two stored procedures one is to `insert` a record to the table, the other is to `update` one column of this record.

The `insert` one runs first, then I will run some other processes (including stored procedures used for other tables.) and finally I will run the `update` stored procedure to update the record as completed.

However, sometimes the `update` one cannot find the match (the one just inserted, I use some variables (one of them is in type datetime) that I passed to the `insert` stored procedure to find the record just inserted then to update. I have used a update trigger to find this reason.)

How can I make sure the data is already in the table before I run the `update`? do I need a `while` loop here?

**EDIT**: I'm running these all in one `BackgroundWorker.DoWork` Eventhandler

Comment: You're essentially looking for a synchronous invocation, which is what `.ExecuteNonQuery()` will accomplish.  How are you invoking it now?

Comment: I use `ExecuteNonQuery()` in both insert and update.

Comment: Are you calling UPDATE from your INSERT proc?  If so, you should be able to pass SCOPE_IDENTITY to the UPDATE proc directly from your INSERT proc...or am I missing something?

Comment: @KevinNelson, No I'm not. I run UPDATE afterwards, as I need to run some other processes in between.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't asynchronous from the sounds of it, so you shouldn't need to have your update script wait for the insert.

Maybe I'm misunderstanding.  However, what is sticking out to me is that you are saying that you are finding the row to update with datetime rather than its identity.  If you have your insert proc return SCOPE_IDENTITY, then pass that to the update proc...it sounds like that should fix your problem where the update cannot find the right row.

Comment: Yes, this is what i'm thinking of. but I just can't understand, why the same datetime I passed to the INSERT cannot be used in the UPDATE? and why this only happens 1 in 100 times.....

Comment: DateTimes as a key would be subject to race conditions.  Assuming your datetime goes out to seconds...If two rows can be inserted during the same second, you then have two updates that are both going to update the same row.  The one row will get updated twice, the other won't.  You can look at your insert dates, but that's one possibility.  The other possibility is if you have any code that could potentially modify the date in any way, that could screw it up.  This is the very purpose of a unique primary key, so that you don't have risk of ambiguity.

Comment: Thank you. The datetime I used goes to fff, it is a local field defined in the C#, so it can't be changed and I need it to be the same in multiple tables and that is what I get now. And it's just one of them as I do use other fields to match.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1021755/compare-two-datetime-values-from-sql-server-with-c-sharp I think this explains why...

Answer (score 0):

Run all DB stuff in one transaction.

Simple Example:

```
using(TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
{
  // init connection, command etc.

  ...

  insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

  ...

  updateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

  scope.Complete();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I can't run them in one transaction as I need a lot processes in between and I can't lock all those tables for so long.

Comment: At least you can explictly commit transaction with insert command. If you won't delete it after that or change the primary key, it should work for you.