# How to convert a date value from sql server with c#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm using WinForms and C#, and I'm trying to compare between a date from the database and the current date.

My code is the following :

```
  DataManager.NotificationManager obj = new DataManager.NotificationManager();

  DataTable dt1 = obj.GetListExpiryDate();

  string currendate = DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

  foreach (DataRow row in dt1.Rows)
  {
    if (DateTime.Parse(row.ItemArray[41].ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")) == currendate)
    {
      MessageBox.Show("Expired carte for the employee" + row["EmpFName"]);
    } //.RowStyles[0].Height = 0; this.tlp_id.ColumnStyles[1].Width = 0; }

    else
    {
      MessageBox.Show(" not Expired carte for the employee" + row["EmpFName"]);
    }
  }
```

The problem is that the data coming from the database doesn't have the same format of the `currentdate` value!

Any ideas please?

Comment: possible duplicate of [compare two datetime values from SQL Server with c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1021755/compare-two-datetime-values-from-sql-server-with-c-sharp)

Comment: `DateTime.Parse()` to get your value from the DB to a `DateTime`

Comment: Just a side note: hard-coding values (like 41) is never a good idea..

Comment: because i have a big table which contains multi rows. else what can i do ?

Comment: Use constants or Enums, this way if things change you only have to make the change in one place - better code maintainability.

Comment: thanks @Milen Pavlov, I will Tyr it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of converting the DateTime to a string in currentdate, convert the return from the database to a DateTime value and compare those.

```
DataManager.NotificationManager obj = new DataManager.NotificationManager();
DataTable dt1 = obj.GetListExpiryDate();
DateTime currendate = DateTime.Today;

foreach(DataRow row in dt1.Rows)
{  
    if (DateTime.Parse(row.ItemArray[41].ToString().Date) == currendate) 
    { 
         MessageBox.Show("Expired carte for the employee" + row["EmpFName"]); 
    }
    else 
    { 
         MessageBox.Show(" not Expired carte for the employee"+row["EmpFName"]); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Do not format the date coming from the database as a string. Instead, use the value as `DateTime`:

```
if (((DateTime)row.ItemArray[41]).Date == DateTime.Today) {
    MessageBox.Show("Expired carte for the employee" + row["EmpFName"]);
}
```

This way formatting would become irrelevant.

Note the use of `.Date` and `DateTime.Today` to ensure that only the date portion would be compared, ignoring the time portion.

Answer (score 0):

If Item 41 is indeed a DateTime object, the simplest thing to do would be:

```
var dt = row[41] as DateTime;
if (dt != null) {
  // process dt as a DateTime object.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While using `DateTime` conversions, I would suggest one to use the `TryParse()`;It allows you to provide an array of strings as your possible input formats.
Here's the most overloaded signature:

```
public static DateTime ParseExact(
    string s,
    string[] formats,
    IFormatProvider provider,
    DateTimeStyles style
)
```